# How to adjust the shift of elements when filling textbox when a keyboard appea (Windows phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0

How can I  adjust the shift of elements when filling textbox (when a keyboard appea ). They move up but not enough.

Update:

I need to improve the functionality like this:(I have 3 textbox and when I click one of them the others should be shown above the keyboard too) Is it possible?